# How to check if the first column names of my data frame exist in a particular oder

Tags: python, pandas

An application I am developing generates at some point data frames in which most of the names of the columns should be exactly the same apart from one column. I am doing some validation and I would like to check if all columns names are in the position they should be.

The problem is that there is one column whose name will change and I cannot test that.

```
header_list = ['one','two','three','????','four','five']
```

what is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the position of the variable column, use:

```
l = list(df.columns)
l.pop(3)
assert l == ['one','two','three','four','five']
```

more generic approach to enable many "blanks":

```
header_list = ['one','two','three','????','four','five']
assert all(col==ref for col,ref in zip(df, header_list) if ref!='????')
```

Comment: I like your first approach and I have taken and adapted it to my code like this ``` header_input.pop(3) 
assert header_input == ['one','two','there','four','five'], log.log_message('ERROR:....) To test if this assert work, I have changed one of the name of the columns (e.g. ones) but I don't gent any error message. The ``` log.log_message() ``` work because in the same script there is another one that does what expected.

Comment: If you have a single "blank", pop is indeed the easiest ;)

Comment: Cannot I put a function after the condition? I mean, cannot I put a function as a message?? I don't get error putting the function as message but neither works.

Comment: can you provide a sample dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I can, but with a picture because I am working in a cluster without access to the internet (I cannot copy and paste). I will add this to the questions.

Comment: You can maybe provide a dummy minimal example, it's more useful that an image ;)